# Adding npm packages to embark framework

Tags: dapp-development, embark

Does the embark framework use browserify for package management?
How do I add a package (say [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer)) to the project?

I used `npm i --save-dev buffer` and can see the dependency added to package.json and the node_modules folder but cannot `var Buffer = require("Buffer")` it. The `var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer` suggested by the docs doesn't work either.

The error in the javascript console in the browser is `Error: Cannot find module 'Buffer'` and `Error: Cannot find module 'buffer/'` respectively.

Comment: Not really an Ethereum question.  You need to translate the code for the browser.  Try browserify.

Comment: The question is regarding adding the package to a specific Ethereum framework, namely Embark.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a general node.js question, not isolated to Embark.

After you've written your code using node.js modules, you must translate it for browser use via Browserify.

Comment: Embark has browserify built-in. That means that I don't have to browserify the code as it is part of the workflow. Furthermore "embark build" (a complete rebuild) does not help.